# Getting Object with key value issue in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, for-loop, internet-explorer-9

I am having an issue that only occurs in IE9, it doesn't happen in Chrome or Firefox.

Basically I have an object called Results, which contains multiple objects. I'm just trying to do a simple loop through the obects in the Results object using the name as a key for each object, but for some reason using the name of the object as a key or trying a number index does not return anything from Results in IE9. Using a number index does not return a object in any browser.

The results object looks like this at runtime, its taken from FireBug so sorry about the format

```
    results
     []

    NUMBER0
    Object { type="textbox", name="NUMBER0", answer="3125"}

    NUMBER1
    Object { type="textbox", name="NUMBER1", answer="135"}
```

Number0 and Number1 are the names of the object inside results.

This is the simple for loop I'm using, item below will have a value of either "Number0" or "Number1":

```
     for (item in results) {
         var question = results[item];
         // do something with question here
     }
```

So as I said in FireFox and Chrome this returns the correct object and I can continue but in IE9 it doesn't work. I haven't tried any other versions of IE and I have made sure that IE9 is not in IE 7 or 8 mode.

Any ideas would be great.

Anthony

Comment: What does the code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `results` is an array `[]`, so if it's not empty, "number index" should work.  Try iterating thru it like this:

```
for (var i=0; i < results.length; i++) {
   var question = results[i]
}
```

Unless it's an empty array object that has other items assigned to it as properties. In that case... I suggest rethinking your design.

Comment: Hi Yuriy, looking at the code again I think you might be right so I have to look into changeing it, I didn't write the original code and unfortunately it hasn't been well documented.